# htaccess redirect 301 without a separator

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

End of the url have numbers without any separator

Given url like

> example.com/productdetails/product-flowers123

needed to redirect

> example.com/productdetails/product-flowers--123

can i do this with .htaccess

I already tried: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/productdetails/([A-Za-z]+)$([0-9]+)$ /productdetails/$1--$2`

But its not worked.

Comment: Your best bet is using `mod_rewrite` for this. Is the URI a query?

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+` does not cover anything but letters, so you are not catching any more than the `product` part with that. And there is no `$` after that part either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(productdetails/.*?[a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)/?$ /$1-$2
```

Make sure to use a new browser or clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I get this error: The page isn’t redirecting properly